# ERROR: The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, serve

I have downloaded a project from the Internet and tried `ng serve` but I got:

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

So I tried this command(as in README file is written the CLI version that the app is generated by is `1.4.9`):

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.4.9
```

I get no errors after this command, but when I try `ng serve` I get the previous error again!
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after updating did you cd back into the angular project the one with src > app ? you have to run this command in the directory where package.json exists

Comment: Where should I run this command: `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.4.9` ?

Comment: ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.4.9 will update your package json run it in the directory where package.json exists assuming you are using npm and when you see your package.json is updated run npm install to actually update angular cli

Comment: So running `npm install` is necessary for that?

Comment: Yes install will download the version mentioned in package.json

Comment: What if you don't know the version of angular cli?

Comment: Thank you for specifying that the proper folder is where the package.json file exists.  Lots of responses just say to make sure you are in the root folder, which is not clear if the Angular files are part of a larger project.  I was tearing my hair out.